# C# Enumerate Regex Matches

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, pattern-matching

What is the best way to enumerate a regex-replacement in C#.

For example if I wanted every **"<intent-filter"** match to be replaced by **"<intent-filter android:label=label#"**. The # sign is a incremental digit. What would be the best way to code it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an incremented counter in the anonymous method specified as the `MatchEvaluator` callback. The `(?<=…)` is positive lookbehind; it is matched by the regex evaluator, but not removed.

```
string input = "a <intent-filter data=a /> <intent-filter data=b />";
int count = 0;
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\<intent-filter)", 
    _ => " android:label=label" + count++);
```

Comment: +1 :-) ooh! shiny! might that be `_ (match) => " android:label=label" + count++);`? Because http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DarenThomas: `_` is used as a *de facto* convention for parameter names in anonymous methods that won't be used in the method body. You can use `match =>` instead.

Comment: argh! you're right! This is such a "I knew that too!" moment for me. Facepalm! This is the correct answer!

Comment: Your code works but I dont understand how your able to look behind without a match to look behind of. There's nothing after or before your parentheses, can you explain how this is possible... and if it's necessary to look behind of a match of nothing?

Comment: @userX: An empty regex pattern is always matched (by any zero-width substring). For example, `Regex.Replace("abc", "", "1")` would be matched at all positions in the string, giving the result `"1a1b1c1"`. If we "prepend" a lookbehind to our empty pattern, we can constrain the positions that are matched. For example, `Regex.Replace("abc", "(?<=b)", "1")` ensures that only the position after `b` is matched, giving the result `"ab1c"`.

Comment: thanks, and what about the counter-variable. It seems that somehow it's internaly looping and increment the counter?? Is this incrementing always possible or is it limited to look-arounds only

Comment: The method delegate passed as the third parameter to the `Regex.Replace` method is called for each match in the source string, so yes, you can think of it as internally looping. Since the `count` variable is captured from the outer scope, it is shared across all invocations of the anonymous method. This incrementing will be possible for any regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with Regexes for this one. Do something along the lines of:

```
var pieces = text.Split(new string[] { "xx" });
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var idx = 0;
foreach (var piece in pieces)
{
    sb.Append(piece);
    sb.Append(" android:label=label");
    sb.Append(idx);
}
// oops, homework assignment: remove the last "<intent-filter android:label=label#"
```